# adding many dictionaries to aspell

Tags: linux, terminal, aspell

I have a tex document spanning several files that I want to check with aspell.
The command I use is:

```
cat $f | aspell list --extra-dicts="./names.spl" --mode=tex -l en |sort -u
```

for every file name f.

Some files that concern pronunciation have "words" like aj and oo inside them, which aspell counts as spelling mistakes. I want to filter them out without putting them into the names.spl dictionary. (first because they are not names, second because they shouldn't be ignored in other files)

[the aspell documentation](http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/4_Customizing.html) states that the "extra-dicts" argument can receive a list, but I can't seem to delimit it properly. I tried , : and plain spaces to no avail. They are either treated as a long file path or get entirely separated from the extra-dicts keywords.

I also tried to use the option twice, but the second time just overrides the first.

Am I missing something trivial about how lists are provided as command line arguments in the terminal?

Comment: I thought this would be a trivial question. Nothing I tried worked to create a `<list>`, whatever that is.

Comment: could the question be migrated there by a moderator or should I reopen it?

Comment: Don't cross post questions

Comment: this question has been closed as off topic several months ago. The closer commented it should be asked on the unix\linux site, and so I did. I don't know why this question is still open to be considered a cross-post. If there is something specific that I can do to remedy this, I'd love to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the texinfo manual (`info aspell`), `aspell` uses a list option format that is different from other GNU programs, in which the base option name is prefixed with `add-` or `rem-` to respectively add or remove items from a list:

> 4.1.1.3 List options ....................
>
> To add a value to the list, prefix the option name with an 'add-' and
>   then specify the value to add.  For example, to add the URL filter use
>   '--add-filter url'.  To remove a value from a list option, prefix the
>   option name with a 'rem-' and then specify the value to remove.  For
>   example, to remove the URL filter use '--rem-filter url'.  To remove
>   all items from a list prefix the option name with a 'clear-' without
>   specify any value.  For example, to remove all filters use
>   '--clear-filter'.

Following this pattern for the `--extra-dicts` option, you would add multiple extra dictionaries as

```
--add-extra-dicts dict1 --add-extra-dicts dict2
```

The documentation for `Aspell 0.60.7-20110707` also mentions a (possibly newer) more direct delimited list format, using a third prefix `lset`:

> A list option can also be set directly, in which case it will be
>   set to a single value.  To directly set a list option to multiple
>   values prefix the option name with a 'lset-' and separate each value
>   with a ':'.  For example, to use the URL and TeX filter use
>   '--lset-filter url:tex'.

Following this format, your option would become

```
--lset-extra-dicts dict1:dict2
```